# Corrplot significance

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I don’t know where I should put like `method=”spearman”` in the codes of corrplot to see the significance of the sperman correlation

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95){
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
n <- ncol(mat)
p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
diag(p.mat) <- 0
diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
for(j in (i+1):n){
tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
}
}
return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars,0.95)
```

Comment: add `method = 'spearman'` to the arguments in your `cor.mtest` function so that it will be the default (and the user can change it later if needed). You will also need to add `method = method` in the `tmp <- cor.test` line

Comment: That's not a very efficient implementation of this. However, the main problem is that it doesn't adjust the p.values for multiple testing.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `method=”spearman”` has to be passed to the `cor.test` function:

```
cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level, method = ”spearman”)
```

See the help page of `?cor.test` for further details.